# generating numbers using a n-bit number (similar to generating subsets of n-bit value)

Tags: c, algorithm, optimization, bit-manipulation

Given a number 'n' and the corresponding binary value. I want to generate all combinations of n, using only the bits set in 'n'.

for example: if n=11 and its binary representation 1011, the combinations are:

```
0000
0001
0010
0011
1000
1001
1010
1011
```

example 2: if n=49 and its binary representation is 11001, the combinations are:

```
00000
00001
01000
01001
10000
10001
11000
11001
```

The easiest way could be to write a C subroutine to generate these combinations, however, i need some efficient way/algorithm for generating these combinations (some bit manipulation techniques similar to [bit twiddling hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#NextBitPermutation)).

Thanks.

Comment: and the question is?

Comment: The question is, I need an efficient bit manipulation technique to generate these combinations.

Comment: why don't you show what you have done and maybe someone can tell you what you can improve. Because now it seems you just want someone to write this code for you.

Comment: There are 2^k combinations, where k is the number of 1's in n.  For each of the 2^k, generate a number that has the corresponding bit set or cleared using a table lookup.

Comment: If you really need an algorithm and not code, then this question should have been asked on math.stackexchange.com instead. However, [Ian Abbott already posted an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42422320/1475978) that is, as far as I can see, optimal. (On typical architectures, it simplifies to a subtraction and a binary and operation per generated number, and generates them in the proper order, too.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an illustration of a technique using simple bit twiddling. It uses the guaranteed semantics of binary arithmetic on unsigned values.

In the expression `i = n & (i - n)` below, all the sub-expressions, `i`, `n`, `(i - n)` and `n & (i - n)` are the same type, `unsigned int` and are unaffected by the integer promotion rules.  Mathematically, the sub-expression `(i - n)` is evaluated modulo 2<sup>m</sup>, where 2<sup>m</sup> - 1 is the maximum value that can be represented by an `unsigned int`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int n = 49;
    unsigned int i;

    for (i = 0; ; i = n & (i - n)) {
        printf("%u", i);
        if (i == n)
            break;
        putchar(' ');
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

**Example step**

Assuming `n` is 49, or 0000000000110001₂, and the current value of `i` is 16, or 0000000000010000₂. Then for 16-bit, 2's complement arithmetic, we have:

```
0000000000010000₂
0000000000110001₂ -
----------------
1111111111011111₂
0000000000110001₂ &
----------------
0000000000010001₂ (= 17)
```

This is vaguely similar to the well-known technique to find the lowest '1' bit in an unsigned value `x` as `x & -x`, which works because ANDing a number with its two's complement leaves only the lowest '1' bit set in the result.

Comment: I only answered because it seemed like a fun challenge!

Comment: I think the (`v(k+1) = (~(n - v(k) - 1)) & n`, `v(0) = 0`, `0 < k < popcount(n)`, `v(k) < v(k+1) < n`) is pretty much optimal. The only "issue" wrt. OP's definition is that this one does not yield `n` itself, whereas OP needs `n` to be the final element in the sequence. Note that `v(k+1) = (v(k) - n) & n` relies on two's complement format for negative integers.

Comment: I simplified the expression for the next iterated value a bit more. It's probably as simple as possible now.

Comment: But it works only on architectures with two's complement format for negative integers, which is not necessarily true. Actually, the `v(k+1) = (~(n - v(k) - 1)) & n` with `v(k) < v(k+1) <= n` *does* yield all the elements in the sequence, so I do believe it is optimal in C. Besides, at least GCC-5.4 optimizes the expression to a simple `sub` and `and` on x86 and x86-64 even with optimizations disabled (`-O0`), so this portable form is just as efficient on arches with two's complement negative integers.

Comment: @NominalAnimal unsigned integers are always 2's complement. It's in the spec.

Comment: When `0 <= i < n`, `i - n` is negative. As your answer currently stands, it relies on binary arithmetic on negative integers.

Comment: @NominalAnimal `i - n` is not negative. It is unsigned.

Comment: Ah. C11 6.2.5p9. Yes, `i - n` is indeed unsigned if and only if both `i` and `n` are unsigned integer types; I didn't notice you had changed them to unsigned integer types. I'm satisfied your solution is optimal -- essentially, with `unsigned` `v` and `n`, `v(k+1) = (v(k) - n) & n = (~(n - v(k) - 1)) & n`, which on most current architectures should both optimize to a subtraction and a binary and operation.

Comment: @NomimalAnimal Although I have tweaked the code several times in my answer (mostly to do with changes of heart in the handling of 0), I have used `unsigned int` consistently in all versions. (For 0, I decided it should just print 0 in the end, since 0 has 0 bits set and I felt that the code should output 2^pop(n) answers.)

Comment: It is quite possible I simply read wrong! I'm often wrong, after all. Note that you can use `2<sup>m</sup>` in your answer, and say `i` and `r` are `m`-bit unsigned integers. If you want to expand your answer wrt. *how*  the algorithm works, then the bit pattern changes are easier to describe via `~(n - v(k) - 1)` (which is, if `n` and `v(k)` are `m`-bit unsigned integers, exactly equivalent to `v(k) - n` in C).

Comment: @NominalAnimal Thanks, I wasn't aware you could use superscripts like that. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the binary string for your number.
2. Create a tree node labeled Z.
3. Let node := Z.
4. Let N := 1.
5. Read symbol N of your string (from the left, 1-indexed)
6. If symbol is 1, add two children of node; label the first child with node's label + 1, the other with node's label + 0. If symbol is 0, add one child of node; label the child with node's label + 0.
7. Increment the value of N.
8. Repeat steps 5 - 7 for all children of node, recursively, until in step 7 you increment the value of N to a value larger than the length of your original binary string. That condition terminates the recursion.
9. Once the tree has been so constructed, the leaves of the tree are labeled with your allowed values. Any tree traversal mechanism which visits the leaves will allow you to recover the allowed binary strings.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating integers through only certain allowed bits? How about this function:

```
int NextMasked (int val, int mask) {
    return ((val | ~mask) + 1) & mask;
}
```

Function step by step:

- take previous value `val` and set all the bits to 1, which are NOT set in the `mask`
- increment resulting value by 1
- now; clear all bits what we set earlier, only allowing same bits what are set in the `mask`
- tada.wav; we have new value and we going to `return` it to caller.

---

Let's test this with your example (`mask = 11` and initially `val = 0`):

```
Here all values are in binary:

val = 0000, mask = 1011, ~mask = 0100 (bits inverted)

(old)                          (new)
val        |~mask   +1          &mask

0000       0100     0101        0001
0001       0101     0110        0010
0010       0110     0111        0011
0011       0111     1000        1000
1000       1100     1101        1001
1001       1101     1110        1010
1010       1110     1111        1011
1011       1111    10000       00000  <-- zeroed, you know it ended
```

Because this was so fun, let's test your another example (`mask = 49`):

```
Here all values are in binary:

val = 00000, mask = 11001, ~mask = 00110 (bits inverted)

(old)                          (new)
val        |~mask   +1          &mask

00000      00110    00111       00001
00001      00111    01000       01000
01000      01110    01111       01001
01001      01111    10000       10000
10000      10110    10111       10001
10001      10111    11000       11000
11000      11110    11111       11001
11001      11111   100000      000000  <-- again, wrapped around (zeroed)
```

It's late and I did not actually tested on the computer. But this should work, or give the idea...